# Start java application after a crash or server restart

Tags: java, shell, ssh, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a few Java applications, mostly with Spring Boot, in different servers (Droplets) from Digital Ocean. Previously I upload each new release manually and with some shell scripts created I am able to start/stop the applications. These scripts contains environment variables when it's necessary for test or production environments. To check if the application is running I have a cronjob launched every 5 minutes, this cronjob execute a shell script to start the application if it's not running.

However I switched to automatic deployments using Bitbucket pipelines and now I won't have shell scripts anymore because all the configuration will provided by the Bitbucket pipeline and will be executed over SSH.

For instance `cat environment.sh start.sh | ssh xxx@yyy` where `environment.sh` is created on the fly by the pipeline with right configuration in that moment for each environment.

How can I do something to start the application automatically if it's not running? Should I upload the script files in each automatic deployment and use a cronjob?

Comment: I think this is reasonable to use scripts. However, if your Linux environment supports `systemd` it would be better to use its facilities, specifically `targets` that do restart automatically. I did this in my previous work

Comment: All the environment variables will be managed over Bitbucket pipeline settings to centralize it and avoid to update manually files on server. So your suggestion is upload it to the server to be able to create new cronjob like I had before. Right? I don't have knowledge about systemd but I will try to check.

Comment: Yes, but without cron. There are basically two initialization systems in Linux: `initd` (older) and the newer `systemd`. Both make it possible to restart the application without cron

Comment: I created a GIST with a sample, however I am not sure if this is ok or not because I cannot test it now: https://gist.github.com/fjtorres/de082ad90d0ff6bbb7db843a16ece7f1

Comment: Something like this, however, I'm not sure the env. variables will be injected this way. Just double check it. Kudos for the speed of learning!

Comment: Do you know if I can star/stop the service over ssh connection? The pipeline can upload new release with the executable and the new ssh files but I am not sure if I can do something like `ssh root@server 'systemctl start my.service'`

Comment: Why not? You eventually may run any thing you want, incl. any `sh` script. If it doesn't work as is, run with `sh -c "systemctl..."`. Also check the `systemctl enable --now...` that starts the target and adds it to autolaunch after server restart

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191742/discussion-between-fjtorres-and-igorepst).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a wrapper. [YAJSW](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/) is popular, free and works (in my experience) well in production systems. The wrapper will restart your process if it crashes and can easily be installed as a service over many different OSes without much effort.

NOTE: I am not affiliated or related in any way to YAJSW.

Comment: I didn't use a service wrapper for my projects, however I guess that at the end my configuration should be in the server to be able to start the service with specific environment variables. Right?